# I want to Pass value to JSON in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

Please give me some example of $http.post. I am new in AngularJS. I want to update a JSON file while retrieving information from user. I want to update values but unable to update a JSON file.
My JSON file is data.json.

```
    { var app=angular.module("APP",[]); 
 app.controller("APPController", function ($scope, $http){
   $scope.add = function(){
   var dataObj={ model:$scope.addModel,
    car: [$scope.option1, $scope.option2, $scope.option3, $scope.option4],
    type: $scope.Type};  
$http.post("data.json",dataObj)  
.success(function(res){console.log("success"+res.records)})  .error(function(res){console.log("error")}); 
 };
   });
  }
```

and here is my data.json file

```
    {
  "records": [
    {
      "model" : "car model",
      "car" : ["num1","num2","num3","num4"],
      "type" : "mode type"
    },
    {
      "model" : "car model",
      "car" : ["num1","num2","num3","num4"],
      "type" : "mode type"
    },
]
}
```

Comment: did you try something?

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the `data object` in 2nd param of the $http.post() method.

I am confused to get the exact context of **update JSON**. But if you want to update the existing variable array in your controller which you are using in view from the response, you can do it it JavaScript way.

Here is a working example for the same. This might help.

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ashishanexpert/zvcx5z38/2/

Answer (score 0):

You don't `POST` data on a JSON file, you make the POST API call to a server.
You can `GET` data from a JSON file.

I suggest you read through Angular's [POST](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#post) documentation first.